# Calling a method in doAsync results - too much work on main thread

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, anko

This is my code which does some background work

```
 fun getAllArtists(): LiveData<List<Artist>> {
    val artistListLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Artist>>()
    doAsync {
        val artistList = MusicGenerator.getAllArtists()
        onComplete {
            getArtistInfo(artistList)
            artistListLiveData.value = artistList
        }
    }
    return artistListLiveData
}
```

On completion I make a network call to get Artist Info

```
private fun getArtistInfo(artistList: List<Artist>) {

    artistList.forEach {

        val url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&api_key=API_KEY&format=json"
                .plus("&artist=")
                .plus(it.artistName)

        val artistInfoList: MutableList<ArtistInfo> = ArrayList()

        apiService.getArtistImage(url)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe({ result ->
                    info { result.toString() }
                }, { error ->
                    error.printStackTrace()
                })

        verbose { artistInfoList.size }
    }
}
```

However, I'm making sure that the network call is in the background thread and results are on the main thread.

But there is jank in the UI, and the logcat says too much work being done on the main thread. I don't get it, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does the warning appear if you don't execute that `getArtistImage` flow?

Comment: The warning does not appear if I do not execute getArtistImage

Comment: However, the warning does not appear if i use Schedulers.computation()

Comment: Is `result.toString()` printing a lot?

Comment: It does not print a lot, but it is executed many times

Comment: As I mention when I use Schedulers.computation() there is no jank, I'm a bit confused when to use io() and computation()

Comment: How many items are in `artistList`? Using `io()` here is correct, assuming you don't overwhelm the system. Also the order is usually `subscribeOn().observeOn()` Try with `Flowable.fromIterable().flatMap()` instead of that outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are creating too many threads.  `io()` is unbounded, and `computation` is based on the processor cores.  Since you are doing io, you should be using `io()`, but also need to take care to not blast a ton of requests at the same time.  You can use a `Flowable.flatMap` to iterate through your list instead of `foreach`.  The key here is to specify a value for the max concurrency to `flatMap`.  Below, I have set it to 4, but you can play around with the number to see what gives you a good result for max requests inflight without creating jank.  Also, since we are using `flatMap`, I moved your `subscribe` outside the loop to process the stream of results coming from `getArtistImage`. It is not clear what you are doing with `artistInfoList` from your code snippet, so I have left it off, but you can use the following as a guide --

```
private fun getArtistInfo(artistList: List<Artist>) {

    Flowable.fromIterable(artistList).flatMap({
        val url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&api_key=API_KEY&format=json"
                .plus("&artist=")
                .plus(it.artistName)

        getArtistImage(url)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    }, 4)
            .subscribe({ result ->
                info { result.toString() }
            }, { error ->
                error.printStackTrace()
            })
}
```